# Windows 10 Visual Studio 2015 .xaml file association

Tags: windows-10, file-association, visual-studio-2015

.xaml files do not seem to associate with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 (they aren't in the list of possible associations in the Settings > Default Apps stuff.

Is there a way to force the association somehow? (or add the option to the "Set Defaults by App" list?)

EDIT: Sorry, should have added a bit more detail...

I've tried "Open With...", but VS2015 isn't in the list of apps. (Visual Studio Version Selector is, but that opens a new instance every time, which isn't what I want).

I can manually find devenv.exe by clicking "Look for another app on this PC", but that gives me a message saying "The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program."

Comment: Have you tried: **Right click a .xaml > Open with... > Set default application > Choose the Studio and at bottom check 'Do this every time' (or something like that) **

Comment: @RACING121 Yep, I should have mentioned it; details now in question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three ways.

- Using the GUI, right-click the file and choose **Open With**, then select Visual Studio (you may need to browse for it, the binary name is `devenv.exe`) and make sure the **Use this app for all .xaml files** option is checked.
- Using the Registry Editor, you can add (or edit) a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` for `.xaml`, and specify a "file type" (if it isn't already set to `Windows.XamlDocument` the way it is for me), then create (or edit) the key for that file type (for example, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.XamlDocument`), and its subkeys `shell\open`, and specify the path that you want it to run. (I recommend looking at other extensions and file types to see the format of the data.)
- Using CMD, with the `assoc` and `ftype` commands. `assoc` gets or sets the file type for an extension, so you can use `assoc .xaml` and find the current file type (if there is one) in the registry, and `assoc .xaml=Windows.XamlDocument` if you want to set it to the value that it is on my box. Then, use `ftype` to get or set the "open" command for that file type. For example, `ftype Windows.XamlDocument=<PATH_TO_VISUAL_STUDIO>\devenv.exe %1`.

Comment: The first way doesn't work (details now in the question). The third way adds visual studio to the possible application list, but although visual studio runs, the file doesn't actually open. However, the second method works great! (I used regedit to copy the key structures of an existing visual studio file entry to a new one for xaml. That makes vs2015 appear in the open with app list, and picking it works fine.)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Strange that the first one fails. You can probably get the third to work if you alter the `ftype` command to match another file type that VS uses, or alter the `assoc` command to use an existing VS file type (the obvious one I see being `VisualStudio.cs.14.0`). It's OK for more than one extension to map to the same file type.

Comment: I had the same experience as @user673679.  I had to parse CBHackings' answer a bit to understand what he said.  What I did was go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cs` since I knew that `.cs` files are correctly associated with Visual Studio.  The key with Name `(Default)` there had `VisualStudio.cs.14.0` as its Data.  I copy/pasted this to the Data of the correspoding key under `.xaml`.